# FaceTexture getting distorted in android build. Works fine in spark ar studio simulator

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I have painted my face texture using the moustache example as a reference using photoshop. In the simulator, it works fine but the texture seems pixelated and distorted in the spark ar player in android.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BvVq.jpg

I have tried playing with the background influence and opacity. 
Both the images are using the same project file with no changes.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! The texture was getting compressed in the android export. I checked the no compression checkbox in the texture settings and it got works perfectly fine now